# How to make columns scroll independently using CSS?

Tags: css

This is my first post here (I'm very new to all this), but I hope I'm asking it correctly.

I'm creating a webpage for my Master's thesis, and I need to have three parallel columns of text that will scroll independently of each other, much like [this template](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/body5.html)

I cannot seem to get the CSS from this template to work on my website, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a better way to achieve this effect.

Thanks so much for you help!

Here's my CSS for [my website](http://capstone.bethanybradshaw.com)

```
    body {
    padding:0;          
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow; hidden;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background:#FFFFFF;     
    }

#title { 

    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    width:100%
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    }

#title h1 {

    font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy, Garamound, serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: 696969;
    line-height: 1px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;   
    }



#title h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    }


#title ul {text-align:center; 
    padding-left, padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    }

#title ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-family: "gill sans mt", "sans-serif";
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    }

#title p{
    font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy Italic, Garamound, serif;
    size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    }


#title a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

#title a:hover {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

/*  column settings */

#allcol {
    position: relative;
    }

#allcol h4{
    text-align: center;
    }

#col1 {
        font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy, Garamound, serif;
        text-align: left;
        float:left;
        background:#DCDCDC;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left:1.5%;
        padding-right:1.5%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width:30%;
        overflow: scroll;
        }

#col2 {     font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy, Garamound, serif;
        text-align: left;
        background: #fff;
        float:left;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left:1.5%;
        padding-right:1.5%;
        width:30%;
        overflow: scroll;
        }

#col3 { font-family: Sorts Mill Goudy, Garamound, serif;
        text-align: left;
        float:left;
        background:#DCDCDC;
        padding-left:1.5%;
        padding-right:1.5%;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        width:30%;
        overflow: scroll;
        }

#footer {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    }
```

Comment: You will have to set a `height` if you want scrollbars to appear.

Comment: `http://capstone.bethanybradshaw.com/Desktop/php/capstonecss.css` and `http://capstone.bethanybradshaw.com/Downloads/css.css` are both returning 404 errors.

Comment: Use this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bYXRT/. It's exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/78PrJ/

Here is a working example. As mentioned, you'll have to set the `div height`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS: `#col1, #col2, #col3{ height: 500px; }` You're already using `overflow: scroll`, so the scrollbars will appear,

Answer (score -2):

`overflow:scroll` only works if the height is specified in `px`. If you specify the height in `%age` it won't work.

Comment: You can use overflow:scroll with relative heights. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bYXRT/